# F# Spawning an Actor with additional parameters

Tags: f#, akka.net

Im thinking how can I spawn an actor with some additional parameters in F# ?

I have the following actor function definition

```
let triggerActor (mailbox: Actor<TriggerCommand>) (name: string, expr : string, jobCallback : JobCallback) =

(...... cutted code, not needed here  )
```

and Im trying to wrap that function to spawn an actor with

```
spawn system name (actorOf2 triggerActor    )
```

but here I run into a troubles... how can I pass those additional params?
I know that I can create a custom C# style actor, but for now I want to try with F# :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not an expert on Akka, but assuming the "extra parameters" are the second argument you can do as follows.

First reverse the order of the formal parameters:

```
let triggerActor (name: string, expr : string, jobCallback : JobCallback) (mailbox: Actor<TriggerCommand>) = ...
```

Then partially apply the function:

```
spawn system name (actorOf2 (triggerActor ("name", "expr", jc )))
```